# Node grpc client error: TypeError: _d.substring is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, grpc, grpc-node

I have encountered strange issue and I am unable to make a call to my grpc server from node.

I am using:

```
"@grpc/grpc-js": "^1.6.8",
"@grpc/proto-loader": "^0.7.0",
```

Node version: 16.14.2
npm version: 8.5.0

And im my client file:

```
const grpc = require('@grpc/grpc-js');
const PROTO_PATH_LOGS_REQUEST = __dirname + '/proto/Attempt.proto';
const protoLoader = require('@grpc/proto-loader');
const AuthService = require('./AuthService');


const packageDefinition = protoLoader.loadSync(
    PROTO_PATH_LOGS_REQUEST, {
        keepCase: true,
        longs: String,
        enums: String,
        defaults: true,
        oneofs: true
    });

const ServiceDefinition = grpc.loadPackageDefinition(packageDefinition).com.example.AttemptService;

    const updateAttempt = async (id, operationStatus) => {


    const client = new ServiceDefinition('127.0.0.1:6513', grpc.credentials.createInsecure());

    console.log(`Created gRPC client`);

    const request = {
        id: id,
        status: operationStatus
    };

    const meta = new grpc.Metadata();
    const token = AuthService.generateServiceToken();
    meta.add('Authorization', `Bearer ${token}`);


    await client.UpdateAttempt(request, meta);
}
```

My proto file:

```
syntax = "proto3";

package com.example;

message AttemptUpdateRequest {
    string id = 1;
    string status = 2;
}

message ContactAttempt {
    string status = 1;
}

service AttemptService {
    rpc UpdateAttempt (AttemptUpdateRequest) returns (ContactAttempt);
}
```

So my app crashes before reaching "Created gRPC client" log.

After putting `new ServiceDefinition('127.0.0.1:6513', grpc.credentials.createInsecure());` inside try catch I received:

```
TypeError: _d.substring is not a function
```

And this error comes from `node_modules\@grpc\grpc-js\build\src\channel.js:202:201` from this lines:

```
   const error = new Error();
   logging_1.trace(constants_1.LogVerbosity.DEBUG, 'channel_stacktrace', '(' + this.channelzRef.id + ') ' + 'Channel constructed \n' + ((_d = error.stack) === null || _d === void 0 ? void 0 : _d.substring(error.stack.indexOf('\n') + 1)));
```

The best part is that commenting this two lines solves this issue... But I need to put my app inside a Docker container so this is not an acceptable solution.

Did anybody encounter similar issue?

Comment: I notice that you load the `AuthService` file, so some code running other than what is mentioned in the question. Is there any chance that you are running code that modifies the `Error` class? This error seems to be caused by the error stack trace being something other than a string. On thing I suggest testing, just to see what happens: remove the line that loads `AuthService` and the lines that create and use the `token` variable, and run the same code again.

Comment: It was it. Tkank you very much!!